# .htacces RewriteRule with multiple variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm new to .htaccess RewriteEngine and I am trying to set up some rewrite rules in my .htaccess file.

I want that this URL: http://www.example.com/index.php?site=home&topic=43 will be rewritten to http://www.example.com/home/43

Here is my Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
# with 1 variable
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1  [NC,L]
# with 2 variables
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&topic=$2  [NC,L]
```

So far so good, it works and I can catch the two variables (site & topic) and show them with $_GET['site'] and $_GET['topic'].

**BUT:**

When I also have a "home.php" File on my webserver and I call http://www.example.com/home then I do not get in the background http://www.example.com/index.php?site=home. Instead of this I get directly the http://www.example.com/home.php File.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for any help!

Comment: See if this Q/A helps any: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895539/htaccess-url-rewrite-behavior-being-overwritten-if-filename-minus-ext-same-as

Comment: thank you for your help, but I receive a "500 Internal Server error" if I add "Options -MultiViews" to the .htaccess File...

Comment: I have now the solution. The problem was actually the MultiViews Option. But I had to put the "Options -MultiViews" before the "RewriteEngine On" line. Now it works without 500 Server error.

Comment: Ah! Good to know. You could add that as your own answer to your question if you'd like. Then you can mark this complete.